# How set 404 HTTP response status from a block?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, 404-page, http-header

I'm trying to set 404 HTTP response status from a block's function.

With this code works

```
http_response_code(404);
exit;
```

but no way to to set the 404 status without exiting, i've found only solutions for controllers.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be modifying the response code with in a block, it should be in the controller. Your block should only contain logic that is used within template files to format data etc.

But in your controller to return a 404 you can use the following after injecting the resultForwardFactory `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory`

```php
return $this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('noroute');
```

I've attached a few core Magento examples of it.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View.php

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Product/View.php